# How to group according to specific date

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, reduce

```
const a = [
  {
    "record_id": "2ff8212f-5ec9-4453-b1f3-91840a3fb152",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1662021991000
    }
  },
  {
    "record_id": "c8c11f97-5eda-4f9b-a6a0-5a3f259c85b6",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1663826452195
    }
  },
  {
    "record_id": "8c23aa44-4113-4feb-92b7-eb265f3e11e2",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1663837445146,
      "Draft": 1663808712701,
      "Active": 1663808565409
    }
  },
  {
    "record_id": "fd88fbfc-a8d3-4a86-b245-0f8334b4f11f",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1663841622113
    }
  },
  {
    "record_id": "e0ed3dcf-943c-48d1-b387-87e758e5ed9a",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1663814717259,
      "Unprepped": 1663841617839
    }
  },
  {
    "record_id": "cef4d093-0ced-4d0d-b9f6-90c2e2687bbe",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1663892940412
    }
  }
]
```

Given the array above, my goal is to group according to date(On Rent).  The key must start on the first day of month and end up to current day.
It should look like this

// Note: if the value dont have Unprepped, it will still display on the key(which is the date it is on rent up to the current date. but if it has a value on Unprepped it will stop on the date..)

> > > > for example today is september 23, 2022

```
const final_result = [
  {
    "Sept 1": [
      {
        //for example this is vehicle23
        record_id: "2ff8212f-5ec9-4453-b1f3-91840a3fb152",
        status_date_activity: {
          "On Rent": 1662021991000
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Sept 2": [...and so on ] // vehicle23 will display here because there is no unprepped  in status_date_activity
  },
  ...and so on..., // vehicle23 will display here because there is no unprepped  in status_date_activity
  {
    "Sept 22":[
       {// vehicle23 will display here because there is no unprepped  in status_date_activity},

      {
        //for example this is vehicle4
        "record_id": "e0ed3dcf-943c-48d1-b387-87e758e5ed9a", 
        "status_date_activity": {
          "On Rent": 1663814717259, 
          "Unprepped": 1663922791000 
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "Sept 23":[
      {// vehicle23 will display here because there is no unprepped  in status_date_activity},
      {
        //vehicle4 will still display in sept 23 and will not display in sept24 because the value of unprepped is only for sept23
        "record_id": "e0ed3dcf-943c-48d1-b387-87e758e5ed9a",
        "status_date_activity": {
          "On Rent": 1663814717259,
          "Unprepped": 1663922791000
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "Sept 24": [...and so on ] // vehicle23 will display here because there is no unprepped  in status_date_activity

  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go i hope it will your match expectation**

but one thing i changed in your data structure is `On Rent` to `On_Rent` if that is real we can't change the timestamp to date
or else if you want only `On Rent` instead of `On_rent` mention in the comment i will send there one line of code to convert that into to original

```js
const a = [
  {
    "record_id": "2ff8212f-5ec9-4453-b1f3-91840a3fb152",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1662021991000
    }
  },
  {
    "record_id": "c8c11f97-5eda-4f9b-a6a0-5a3f259c85b6",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1663826452195
    }
  },
  {
    "record_id": "8c23aa44-4113-4feb-92b7-eb265f3e11e2",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1663837445146,
      "Draft": 1663808712701,
      "Active": 1663808565409
    }
  },
  {
    "record_id": "fd88fbfc-a8d3-4a86-b245-0f8334b4f11f",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1663841622113
    }
  },
  {
    "record_id": "e0ed3dcf-943c-48d1-b387-87e758e5ed9a",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1663814717259,
      "Unprepped": 1663841617839
    }
  },
  {
    "record_id": "cef4d093-0ced-4d0d-b9f6-90c2e2687bbe",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1663892940412
    }
  }
]

const fun = (ar)=>{
const hetMap = ar.map((e, i)=>{
  var modifyItem;
   for(x in e.status_date_activity){
      modifyItem = x.split(' ').join('_')
      if(x.split(' ').length > 1){
         e.status_date_activity[modifyItem] = e.status_date_activity[x]
        delete e.status_date_activity[x]
}
       
   }
  const d = new Date(e.status_date_activity.On_Rent)
  const month = d.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    month: 'long',
  });
  const date = d.getDate()
   const getPerfectFormat = `${date} ${month}`
   const Data ={ [getPerfectFormat] :[{
     record_id : e.record_id,
     status_date_activity : e.status_date_activity
}]}
return Data
})
return hetMap
}
console.log(fun(a))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need to combined all data that belong to september 22..and also it should start in semtember 1 followed by semptember 2....an so on until it reaches to current date. Also the data in september 1 should be also in semptember 2 untill in currentDate unless it has an unprepped value

Comment: @cypher could you mark my answer as right. if you satisfied with it. and can you post the different question about what you want in next step. anyway thanks!!

Comment: @cypher ok i understand you want sorting elements by date and merge objects into single array if dates are repeated

Comment: I want to sort and if the date are repeated it should only display only one

Answer (score 0):

**can you try this once**
Is this the way you want to get the output ?

```js
const a = [
  {
    "record_id": "2ff8212f-5ec9-4453-b1f3-91840a3fb152",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1662021991000
    }
  },
  {
    "record_id": "c8c11f97-5eda-4f9b-a6a0-5a3f259c85b6",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1663826452195
    }
  },
  {
    "record_id": "8c23aa44-4113-4feb-92b7-eb265f3e11e2",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1663837445146,
      "Draft": 1663808712701,
      "Active": 1663808565409
    }
  },
  {
    "record_id": "fd88fbfc-a8d3-4a86-b245-0f8334b4f11f",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1663841622113
    }
  },
  {
    "record_id": "e0ed3dcf-943c-48d1-b387-87e758e5ed9a",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1663814717259,
      "Unprepped": 1663841617839
    }
  },
  {
    "record_id": "cef4d093-0ced-4d0d-b9f6-90c2e2687bbe",
    "status_date_activity": {
      "On Rent": 1663892940412
    }
  }
]
const fun = (ar, obj)=>{
  const getSort = ar.sort((a, b)=> new Date(a.status_date_activity["On Rent"]) - new Date(b.status_date_activity["On Rent"]));
//   console.log(getSort)
const hetMap = getSort.map((e, i)=>{
  var modifyItem;
   for(x in e.status_date_activity){
      modifyItem = x.split(' ').join('_')
      if(x.split(' ').length > 1){
         e.status_date_activity[modifyItem] = e.status_date_activity[x]
        delete e.status_date_activity[x]
}
       
   }
  const d = new Date(e.status_date_activity.On_Rent)
  const month = d.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    month: 'long',
  });
  const date = d.getDate()
   const getPerfectFormat = `${date} ${month}`
   const Data ={ [getPerfectFormat] :[{
     record_id : e.record_id,
     status_date_activity : e.status_date_activity
}]}
return Data
})

  hetMap.forEach((e, i)=>{
    for(x in e){
     obj[x] = e[x]
}
})
return obj
}
console.log(fun(a ,{}))
```

Comment: @cypher can you check this code once.